# Spotify Unity SDK

Tags: spotify

Does anyone know, do I need any kind of addition rights (or license agreements) for implementing custom Unity wrapper for Spotify SDK? On its own, the Spotify Unity wrapper will not include any Spotify libs (no Android nor iOS). Each developer will be prompted to download appropriate SDK from the official Spotify website and import into Unity project manually.

I am considering the possibility of selling the custom Unity wrapper for Spotify SDK on the market (Unity Asset Store etc.). I will NOT sell any Spotify resources/libs, just my custom implementation of Unity wrapper for Spotify. But anyway, I need the information about the possible required granted permissions from the Spotify itself.

If you have any kind of useful information according to this case, please, share with me. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I would be very interested in such a wrapper, if it supported streaming as well. How far did you come with that project?

Answer (score 0):

I can't give any specific legal advice, I'd suggest you approach a legal expert - but it's worth checking out Spotify's [Developer Terms of Service](https://developer.spotify.com/developer-terms-of-use/), specifically noting the excerpt *"Unless you receive Spotify’s written approval, you shall not use the Spotify Platform to incorporate Spotify Content into any game functionality"*.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But it's hard to find the right person from Spotify to talk about it. I had a conversation with Spotify Support Engineers, but the result is not satisfying. They couldn't help me and just guiding me to Spotify developer forums.
Do you have any additional information, that may help me to find the right way in this case? I'll appreciate any kind of helpful feedback.

Comment: I work as a developer advocate engineer at Spotify, please feel free to reach out to me at developer-support@spotify.com